# Can this query to search a database of spreadsheet cells be made faster?

Tags: query-optimization, sql-server-2008-r2

I've got every cell of a collection of spreadsheets in a table.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[SheetRow](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    [DocumentName] [varchar](max) NULL,
    [SheetName] [varchar](max) NULL,
    [RowNumber] [varchar](max) NULL,
    [ColumnNumber] [varchar](max) NULL,
    [Value] [varchar](max) NULL)
```

And a query to find all the cells rows with values matching a certain string:

```
select *
from sheetrow a 
inner join sheetrow b
on
    a.value like '%starting balance%' and
    a.DocumentName=b.DocumentName and
    a.SheetName=b.SheetName and
    a.RowNumber=b.RowNumber
```

With 34K cell (rows) in the table, the query took 41 seconds.

Is there an obvious better/faster way to get the same result?

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you use a LIKE query with a wildcard at the beginning, such as `'%starting balance%'` in your example, you destroy the optimiser's ability to use any indexes to speed up the query. So if you can be confident that the cell you are looking for will start with 'Starting balance' then you can remove the first wildcard and make use of any indexes on the `value` column.

Speaking of indexes, you might try creating some. I'm no expert, but I would try one on `value` and one for the other 3 columns in your join condition (`DocumentName`, `SheetName`, and `RowNumber`) to start with.

When trying to determine the reason for a slow query, a good first step is to run the SQL:

```
SET IO STATISTICS ON
GO
```

in the query window you are using, and then run your query. Also enable the Actual Execution Plan before running the query. Once the query has run, you will be able to see detailed statistics in the Messages tab, and you want to look for tables with really high logical reads, physical reads or scan counts. Then see if there are expensive operations in the execution plan working with those tables, and see if there is a way you can improve the efficiency of that operation.

One final tip when trying to find why queries are slow: Install and use the free [SQL Sentry Plan Explorer](http://www.sqlsentry.com/plan-explorer/sql-server-query-view.asp) tool to get a much more detailed and helpful view of execution plans. You will find it *sooo* much more helpful than the default execution plan viewer in SSMS.

Answer (score 0):

Don't think I understand what you're trying to do. Why do you need to have one sheetrow joining another? Can't it just be:

```
select *
from sheetrow a 
where a.value like '%starting balance%'
```

Comment: since every row represents a single cell of a spreadsheet, i want the result of the above query and also the cells with the same row number - this is kind of in the mode of "for fun", btw...